# Metric spaces and fix point

Tags: metric-spaces

I saw this problem in my course of Intr. to the topology:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and 
>   $$f :(X,d) \rightarrow (X,d)$$
>   a continuous function such that: $\quad d(f(x);f(y)) < d(x;y)$, if $x\neq y$.
>
> Prove that $f$ has an unique fix point in $X$.

Well, after proving these statements I could resolve the problem, I think,

- $\forall k\in \mathbb{N} : d(x_{k+1};x_k)\leq \alpha^k d(x_1;x_0)$
- $\forall k\in \mathbb{N} : d(x_k,x_0)\leq (1+ \dots + \alpha^{k-1}) d(x_1;x_0)$

> where: $x_1 = f(x_0)$ and $$\forall n\in \mathbb{N} : x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$$

but it's the right way?

-Thank you for all.

Comment: for uniqueness use two fixed points into your inequality

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Consider the real valued continuous function $g:X \to \mathbb R$ defined as $$  g(x) = d(x, f(x)) $$
As the space $X$ is compact, $g$ achieves its minimum, say at  $x_0.$

If we assume $g(x_0) > 0,$ then calculate $$ g(f(x_0)) = d(f(x_0), f(f(x_0))  ) < d(x_0, f(x_0)) = g(x_0),   $$ which is a contradiction of the minimality of $g(x_0).$ So, in fact, $g(x_0) = 0$ and so $f(x_0) = x_0$ shows the fixed point.
For uniqueness see my comment.

Comment: Thank you very much! This proof is simple and elegant.

Comment: wow, interesting.

Comment: @RaziehNoori glad that you enjoyed it!