# For a Compact Metric Space $T: X\to X$ has unique fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

given: $(X,d)$ is a compact metric space $T:X\to X$ is such that $d(T(x),T(y))<d(x,y)\ \forall x,y\in X$ with $x\neq y$.

Prove that T has a unique fixed point.

Attempt:
I think I can prove Uniqueness:

Consider $T(x)=x$ and $T(y)=y,\ x\neq y$

Then, $d(x,y)=d(T(x),T(y))<d(x,y)$ (contradicting original condition).

However, I am having trouble executing the proof that the fixed point exists.

Comment: see this beautiful answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1278265/metric-spaces-and-fix-point

Comment: Not that I don't like my own answer but that's a whole lot easier! BTW, for uniqueness, if x=T(x) and y=T(y) with $x \ne y$  then d(x,y)=D(T(x),T(y))<d(x,y) which is aburd

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $X_0 = X$ and $X_{i+1} = T(X_i)$. What can you say about $\bigcap_i X_i$?

> For any subset $Y$ of $X$, define the diameter $D(Y)$ of $Y$ to be
>  $\sup\{d(x, y) \mathrel{|} x, y \in Y\}$. Then if $Y$ has more than
>  one point, $D(Y) > 0$ and, if $Y$ is also closed (and hence compact),
>  there are $x, y \in Y$ such that $d(x, y) = D(Y)$ (because 
>  $d : Y \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function on a compact space
>  and hence achieves its maximum value). Taking $Y = T(Z)$ for $Z$ any
>  closed subset of $X$, this gives us points $x, y \in Z$ such that $D(T(Z)) = d(T(x), T(y)) < d(x, y) \le D(Z)$.
>  
>  
>  Now with $F = \bigcap_i X_i$, we have that $F$ is non-empty and closed
>  (as the intersection of a collection of non-empty closed subsets of
>  the compact set $X$) and satisfies $T(F) = F$. By the above remarks
>  $D(T(F)) = D(F) < D(F)$, giving a contradiction, unless $F$ contains
>  exactly one point, which is the desired fixed point of $T$.

Comment: How do you prove that the intersection is a singleton?

Comment: @Dominik: my answer was just intended as a hint to encourage the OP to think about iterating $T$.

Comment: I know, but I'm curious myself as to how this proof works. I know the intersection is nonempty, but I can't prove that it is a singleton.

Comment: @Dominik: I have put a corrected version of a proof that the intersection is non-empty into my answer. (I still can't get the spoiler mark-up to work).

Comment: I fixed it, you need to write ">!" in every line of a spoiler. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Dominik: thanks for the tip on the mark-up.

Answer (score 1):

This may be long but I'm including  every conceivable detail.(1) To avoid the trivial case, assume  $X \ne  \phi$...............(2) By the standard $ \epsilon , \delta$ method we see that  $T$ is continuous.................. (3) For any non-empty closed   $S \subset X $, let $D(S)= \sup \{d(x,y) : x,y \in S\}$. We have $  D(S)\leq D(X)<\infty$ because any metric on a compact space is a bounded metric......................(4) For non-empty closed  $S\subset X$ , if $S$ has at least $2$ members then  $D(T(S))<D(S)$. PROOF : If not, let $(x_n)_n$ and $(y_n)_n$ be sequences in  $S$  with $\lim_{n \to \infty}
\ d(T(x_n),T(y_n))= D(S)$.By selecting  convergent subsequences of $(x_n)_n$ and  $(y_n)_n$  we may suppose WLOG (without loss of generality) that $(x_n)_n$ converges to $x$ and $(y_n)_n$ converges to $y$ with $x, y  \in S$  (because  $S$ is closed).  But by continuity of $T$, we have $0 \ne D(S)= \lim_{n \to \infty}d(T(x_n),T(y_n))=d(T(x),T(y))<d(x,y) \le D(S)$, a contradiction..........................(5)As Rob Arthan suggests, let $X_0=X$ and $X_{n+1}=T(X_n)$. The continuous image of a compact space is compact, so if $X_n$ is closed, it is compact, so $X_{n+1}=T(X_n)$ is compact, hence $X_{n+1}$ is closed.By induction every $T_n$ is closed.We also have  $X_n \subset X_{n-1}$ for every positive integer $n$ by induction, for if $ X_n \subset X_{n-1}$ then $X_{n+1}=T(X_n)\subset T(X_{n-1})=X_n$ .Obviously $\phi \ne X_n$ for all $n$..........................(6) Since $X$ is compact, the set  $ Y=\cap_n X_n \ne \phi$ is non-empty, and also closed................  (7) We have T(Y)=Y. PROOF : Let $y \in Y$ .For each $n$ we have $y \in X_{n+1}=T(X_n)$ so choose $x_n \in X_n$ with $T(x_n)=y$.  Now as before, by choosing a subsequence of $(x_n)_n$ we may assume WLOG that $(x_n)_n$ converges to a point $x$.  We have $x \in X_n $ for every $n$ because $X_n$ is closed and $(x_j)_{j \geq n}$ is a sequence in $X_n$ converging to $x$ .So $x \in \cap_n X_n =Y$, so by continuity of $T$ we have $T(x)=y$  . So we have $Y \subset T(Y)$ .On the other hand, $z \in Y \implies (\forall n (T(z) \in T(X_n)=X_{n+1}\subset X_n)) \implies (\forall n (T(z) \in X_n))\implies T(z) \in Y$ .So we have $T(Y)\subset Y.$ ......................(8) FINALLY if $Y$ had more than one member then by (4) we have $D(T(Y)<D(Y)$ which is absurd because $T(Y)=Y$.And $Y\ne \phi$ so for some $y$ we have $\{y\}=Y=T(Y)=\{T(y)\}.$ QED.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it simple, using only elementary tools in analysis, you can just define the sequence $x_{n+1}=T(x_n)$, with $x_0$ arbitrary. First claim that the sequence is bounded (why?). Then prove that the sequence is Cauchy (you will need the previous step here). Then argue that the sequence converges since the space is also complete (why?). Finally, show that the limit is a fixed point for $T$ (this is an immediate consequence of the fact that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy).

As for the uniqueness, your proof is good.